# Can I use simplexml_load_file($url) without the automatic escaping of $url?

Tags: php, xml, url

I am trying to use simplexml_load_file($url) with

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/dir/file.php?id=test&output=xml";
```

Now, unfortunately simplexml_load_file() automatically escapes all ampersands and replaces them with "& amp;"s - which in turn breaks file.php because for some weird reason it can't handle "& amp;" but only regular ampersands.

Is it possible to somehow load a file without escaping the URL so that I keep my regular & instead of "& amp;"s?

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/file_get_contents instead?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is:

```
$xml = simple_xml_load_file(file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/dir/file.php?id=test&output=xml"));
```

**Edit:**

I've tried the following code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/dir/file.php?id=test&output=xml'));
```

The test was against our XML API. I have checked the Request with a sniffer. In the request is no html special char and no other encoding.

Comment: same result unfortunately... file_get_contents escapes the URL also which causes my file.php to return 500... (however, file.php is not in my control so I can't figure out why & and '& amp;' aren't treated similar. other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go so far as calling that **the** correct way, simply from the standpoint of some hosting providers disabling allow_url_fopen in the PHP.ini settings, which also affects file_get_contents. If that setting is disabled on your server, it might be worth your while to look into PHP's cURL functions, instead. Unless something incredibly hinky is going on, cURL won't mangle the ampersand, either.

Answer (score 0):

Or [file()-function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), if you wish to store the data into an array.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( file_get_contents( 'http://my.url.com' ) );
```